# CORS Error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: jquery, node.js, cors

I am getting this error but everything required for CORS is defined on Node.js server.

I am using localhost:3000

Frontend Code :

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://testing.com/iverse.json",
    success : function(result) {
        console.log("here is the result===",result);
        }
    });
```

Node.js Code for headers

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, ajax, access-key');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  next();
});
```

Please let me know where is the error ?

Comment: On which side are you setting the headers? the one serving the JS or the requested one?

Comment: i am setting headers on the localhost node.js server

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-* headers have to be provided on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has to be provided from the requested resource.

Take a look at [this stackoverflow question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

just use this cors modlue

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

it help to you